# Skyrim add to favorites bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I don't know how I managed to do this, but suddenly adding to favorites stopped working, I cannot add or remove from my favorite list. Has anyone else encountered this bug? If yes what is the fix for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What platform are you playing on? If on the PC, could you list the mods you have installed?

Comment: I'm playing on PC and I only have DawnGuard installed (and Alduin's Son, Frostmourne, The asteria are installed as well but they are turned off) Since I installed Dawnguard I didnt intall or remove anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to key bindings.  If the <kbd>F</kbd> key is bound to something other than the default binding, then there may be issues adding items to favorites.

If you did rebind the key, you can try resetting the key bindings to default:

Note: this is for the steam version of the game.

1. In Explorer, navigate to:
   `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim\Data`
2. Cut and paste the  `Skyrim - Interface.bsa` file to your desktop or other safe place.
3. Start the game.  The keyboard bindings should be reset to default.

Reference:
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-/61000928
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-/60959665
http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2278378

Comment: That didn't work. When I deleted Skyrim - Interface.bsa I couldn't start skyrim. However on the 3rd link u posted they recomended downloading a fix from here http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/368/? and that fixed my problem. Thanks for your help!